# Race condition with waitgroup and unbuffered channel

Tags: go, race-condition

After getting (the right) solution to my initial problem in this post [Understanding golang channels: deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687392/understanding-golang-channels-deadlock), I have come up with a slightly different solution (which in my opinion reads better:

```
// Binary histogram counts the occurences of each word.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

var data = []string{
    "The yellow fish swims slowly in the water",
    "The brown dog barks loudly after a drink ...",
    "The dark bird bird of prey lands on a small ...",
}

func main() {
    histogram := make(map[string]int)
    words := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, line := range data {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(l string) {
            for _, w := range strings.Split(l, " ") {
                words <- w
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(line)
    }

    go func() {
        for w := range words {
            histogram[w]++
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    close(words)

    fmt.Println(histogram)
}
```

It does work, but unfortunately running it against race, it shows 2 race conditions:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c420082180 by main goroutine:
...
Previous write at 0x00c420082180 by goroutine 9:
...
Goroutine 9 (running) created at:
  main.main()
```

Can you help me understand where is the race condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to read from `histogram` in `fmt.Println(histogram)` which is not synchronized to the write of the goroutine mutating it `histogram[w]++`. You can add a lock to synchronize the writes and reads.

e.g.

```
var lock sync.Mutex

go func() {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    for w := range words {
        histogram[w]++
    }
}()

//...
lock.Lock()
fmt.Println(histogram)
```

Note you can also use a `sync.RWMutex`.

Another thing you could do is to wait for the goroutine mutating `histogram` to finish.

```
var histWG sync.WaitGroup
histWG.Add(1)
go func() {
    for w := range words {
        histogram[w]++
    }
    histWG.Done()
}()

wg.Wait()
close(words)
histWG.Wait()

fmt.Println(histogram)
```

Or simply use a channel to wait.

```
done := make(chan bool)
go func() {
    for w := range words {
        histogram[w]++
    }
    done <- true
}()

wg.Wait()
close(words)
<-done

fmt.Println(histogram)
```